# Monitor sleep on MacBook with Ubuntu Server w/o X

Tags: server, suspend, display, macbook, console

My old MacBook should be used as a home server. 
How can i activate a display sleep on the console. There is no X installed. It's the first time I'm using a cli only installation.

At the moment there is a 17.x version installed, I want to upgrade it to 18.4 if I can solve the display problem. I don't need the "light" in my network rack :-)

I don't know how to start a search for this topic because it's quite special with a Notebook :-)

kr basti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Old Ubuntu versions**. This may still work with 17.xx
Seek for this line in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

You may add the option `consoleblank=1`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=1"
```

**OR**
Try `setterm --help | grep power` to find the `powersave` and `powerdown` options. You'll find a way to set a 'suspend' delay.

**OR**
You may also have a look to [TLP laptop mode tools](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

Comment: cannot be more precise because i dunno how the MacBook hw is handled...

Comment: thanks, the command "setterm -blank 1 -powersave powerdown -powerdown 1" worked quite well

now i tried to add the consoleblank=1 and called "sudo update-grub".

Comment: i had to change "consoleblank=60" because

consoleblank => seconds

Comment: which version of Ubuntu & Grub ?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, only cli

grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8

i found the hint about the seconds here: https://superuser.com/a/154388